# Python error with multiprocessing and Tkinter

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, winapi, tkinter

Here is an example of using multiprocessing without Tkinter that works normally. It finds a designated window of another process and tries to set it as the foreground window. I am doing this to allow long-running tasks to run in a separate process from a Tkinter app. The example below is a simplified version of the app that demonstrates the problem.

Worker.py

```
# Worker.py
import multiprocessing

class Worker:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.work_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.running = True
        self.process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.process_commands)
        self.process.start()
    def do_work (self):
        self.work_queue.put('work')
    def do_quit (self):
        self.work_queue.put('quit')
    def process_commands (self):
        while self.running:
            cmd = self.work_queue.get()
            if cmd == 'quit':
                self.running = False
            elif cmd == 'work':
                import win32gui
                hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Untitled - Notepad')
                win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
```

Main2.py

```
# Main2.py
import Worker

class App:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.worker = Worker.Worker()
    def do_work (self):
        self.worker.do_work()
    def exit (self):
        self.worker.do_quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.do_work()
    app.exit()
```

However, when I try to do the same thing from a Tkinter app I get an error.

Main.py

```
# Main.py
import Tkinter as tk
import Worker

class App:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.worker = Worker.Worker()
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.exit)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.button = tk.Button(self.root, text='Go', command=self.do_work)
        self.button.pack()
        self.statusbar = tk.Label(self.root, text='', bd=1, relief=tk.SUNKEN, anchor=tk.W)
        self.statusbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
        self.update_status('Ready')
        self.frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.root.mainloop()
    def do_work (self):
        self.update_status('Doing work...')
        self.worker.do_work()
    def exit (self):
        self.worker.do_quit()
        self.root.quit()
    def update_status (self, status):
        self.statusbar.config(text=status)
        self.statusbar.update_idletasks()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
```

Here is the error I get when running the Tkinter app in Main.py:

```
C:\Scripts\Testing>python Main.py
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Scripts\Testing\Worker.py", line 21, in process_commands
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
error: (0, 'SetForegroundWindow', 'No error message is available')
```

One item of note: SetForegroundWindow has a restriction that it must be run from the current foreground window. If you try to call SetForegroundWindow from a background window, it will fail. I thought this might be the problem, but if the process calling SetForegroundWindow was created by the process of the foreground window it will allow it, so I don't think this is the issue. I verified that the worker process is a child process using Process Explorer:

[image: Parent and child python.exe processes]

I also thought the window handle may be incorrect, but I manually verified the correct window handle is being passed to SetForegroundWindow.

**EDIT**: A slightly simpler version, single module and no class, produces the same error:

Main3.py

```
# Main3.py
import Tkinter as tk
import multiprocessing

def process_commands (work_queue):
    running = True
    while running:
        cmd = work_queue.get()
        if cmd == 'quit':
            running = False
        elif cmd == 'work':
            import win32gui
            hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Untitled - Notepad')
            print hwnd
            win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)


class App:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.work_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.process = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_commands, args=(self.work_queue,))
        self.process.start()

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.exit)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.button = tk.Button(self.root, text='Go', command=self.do_work)
        self.button.pack()
        self.statusbar = tk.Label(self.root, text='', bd=1, relief=tk.SUNKEN, anchor=tk.W)
        self.statusbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
        self.update_status('Ready')
        self.frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        self.root.mainloop()
    def do_work (self):
        self.update_status('Doing work...')
        self.work_queue.put('work')
    def exit (self):
        self.work_queue.put('quit')
        self.root.quit()
    def update_status (self, status):
        self.statusbar.config(text=status)
        self.statusbar.update_idletasks()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
```

Comment: I'm not sure; I don't see where you start Notepad, so I have to assume [you are violating the very strict rules of `SetForegroundWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Notepad is started manually before the Python script. I used `threading` instead of `multiprocessing` and it worked fine, so I am assuming there is something not obvious happening with the multiple processes when Tkinter is involved that `SetForegroundWindow` does not like.